# How do I launch my app from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, icons, center, launch

We have an Android app that has been submitted to the App Center. My app's icon is displayed in the Facebook app list. When the icon is clicked I would expect the app to launch.  Instead the Play Store is launched with the app page for my app.  An open button appears confirming that the app FB is trying to launch and my app are one and the same.  I have double checked the package name and class name in the FB developer settings against my android app manifest.  Does anyone have any advice on how to get my app to launch instead of the Play Store page for the app?  I have set up an entire new project as a test and reproduced this behavior.

Comment: Here are some interesting logcat outputs.

From our app:
07-10 09:45:52.796: I/ActivityManager(419): Displayed com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity

From an app that behaves correctly:

07-10 09:46:34.971: I/ActivityManager(419): Start proc com.dragonplay.slotcity for activity com.dragonplay.slotcity/com.dragonplay.farmslot.screens.SelectAddressActivity: pid=13932 uid=10236 gids={3003, 1015}

07-10 09:46:35.471: I/ActivityManager(419): Displayed com.dragonplay.slotcity/com.dragonplay.farmslot.screens.SelectAddressActivity: +585ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, your hash key is probably wrong.  It can be tricky to get the hash key right, make sure you use your production key store and specify an alias.  Here is a sample command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias mykey -keystore YOURKEYNAME | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

If you give the wrong command you will still get a key but the value will be wrong and when that happens you will see the behavior you see, that the Play Store gets launched for your app.

Comment: Worked! Turns out my key hash was incorrect. Took a while for the changes to propagate to all phones. Also note that the alias "mykey" is different for each keystore.